# Execute class function stored in variable on demand

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, functools

I have two classes with functions:

```
from functools import partial

class A:
  def __init__(self, collection):
    self.collection = collection

  def filter(self, val):
    for element in self.collection:
      if element.var == val:
        return element

class B:
  def __init__(self, var):
    self.var = var

  def test(self):
    print('Element with variable ', self.var)
```

Now I want to have a class that can call a function on an object, fetched on the fly by another function, both stored in a variable and all executed when a certain function was called:

```
class C:
  def __init__(self, fetch, function):
    self.fetch = fetch
    self.function = function

  def run(self):
    global base
    # -----
    # This is the code I need
    base.fetch().function()
    # ... and currently it's completely wrong
    # -----

c = C(partial(A.filter, 5), B.test)

base = A([B(3), B(5), B(8)])

c.run()
```

Should print: `Element with variable 5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `base` into `run` instead of messing with `global`.  `base` doesn't have a `fetch` method, so you have to call the `fetch` function you have as an attribute with `base` as an argument.  You can then send the return value of that call to `function`.

You're also applying `partial` to `A.filter` slightly wrong.  Positional arguments are applied in order, so `partial(A.filter, 5)` will try to bind `5` to `self`, which will throw everything off. Instead, we need to give it the name of the parameter we wish to bind `5` to.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, fetch, function):
        self.fetch = fetch
        self.function = function
    def run(self, a):
        return self.function(self.fetch(a))

c = C(partial(A.filter, val=5), B.test)
c.run(A([B(3), B(5), B(8)]))
# Element with variable  5
```